# Check if method run statically or from instance in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Writing a little method that I would like to work both as a method in an object and statically run from the prototype.

Here is an example:

```
function Obj() {}

Obj.prototype.func = function() {

    if( this.instantiated ) { // Yes I know this is not valid code!

        // instantiated code here

    } else {

        // instantiated code here

    }

};

var myObj = new Obj();

myObj.func();

Obj.prototype.func();
```

How can I tell if the this variable is from an instance or just the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
if (this instanceof Obj)
```

or

```
if (this.constructor === Obj)
```

or

```
if (this !== Obj.prototype)
```

though that is more fragile (think `var foo = Obj.prototype.func;`).

You could also have some kind of "magic" property you set on the instance in the constructor function and test for it's existence, just like you did with `this.instantiated`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can help by coming from the other side.

A pattern I use in my OO JavaScript is this:

```
var Obj = function() {
    var self = (this instanceof Obj) ? this : Object.create(Obj.prototype);

    // constructor code here    

    return self;
};
```

This way when using `Obj` if you forget to use the `new` keyword you still always get a new instance.

Comment: That doesn't help with `Obj.prototype.func();` though.

Comment: True, but once defined, how often do you call a function like that?

Comment: It seems to be what the OP wants to do though: *"I would like to work both as a method in an object and statically run from the prototype."*